# How to change TcxGridColumn's PopupWidth in runtime?

Tags: delphi, devexpress, tcxgrid

I'm using a `TcxGridColumn` which works as a Memo(blobEditKinf = bekMemo), the properties `PopupHeight` and `PopupWidth` on the `RepositoryItem` are fixed at 200/250, how can I change this to another value in runtime if I can't access those properties in code:

```
MyColumn.RepositoryItem.Properties
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this quite easily by doing a suitable cast of the column's `Properties` property.
In the following, my BlobEdit column is for the `Description` memo field of
a TClientDataSet:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  [...]
  if cxGrid1DBTableView1Description.Properties is TcxBlobEditProperties then begin
    TcxBlobEditProperties(cxGrid1DBTableView1Description.Properties).PopUpWidth := 500;
    TcxBlobEditProperties(cxGrid1DBTableView1Description.Properties).PopUpHeight := 500;
  end;
end;
```

Many of the TcxGrid column editors have `Properties` types with type-specific sub-properties that you can access in a similar way to the above.